# Размытие фона для модального окна

Tags: javascript, css, blur, modal

Задачка не супер сложная и в примере я изложу один вариант решения, а так же его недостатки. Хотелось бы узнать, может кто имеет отличный рецепт быстро и красиво работающий. Итак, для начала посмотрим на код и внешний вид:

```js
function modal() {
  var element = document.getElementById("test");
  element.classList.toggle("modal-open");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background: #333;
  height: 20vh;
}

.article {
  min-height: 60vh;
}

.middle {
  margin: 30px auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.modal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -150px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.modal-open>*:not(.modal) {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="modal-open">

  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="article">
    <div class="middle">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal"><button onclick="modal()">Жми сюда</button></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

</div>
```

Для понимания. При открытии окна в `body` подставляется класс и можно играться с размещёнными элементами внутри. Я делаю размытие всех элементов, кроме самого окна. Вроде всё хорошо. Но:

[image: размытие в углах] [image: должно быть]

1. Не красиво смотрится размытие по краю окна браузера, когда есть тёмный фон. Идеи, как его вытянуть за пределы экрана? Можно пробовать `scale`, но такое себе решение.
2. Слишком тяжело это дело для браузера. Если страница большая и куча элементов внутри, размытие всего этого, особенно плавное - не простая задача.

Может у кого есть мысли или готовое решение по "идеальному" размыванию фона?

Answer (score 2):

проблема Вашего решения ещё в том, что элементы с `position: fixed;` будут ломаться

```js
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('blur');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 80px;
}

.main {
  padding: 100px 150px;
  height: calc(100vh - 160px);
}

.footer {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 80px;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 60;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blur {
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.modal__inner {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>

<main class="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui, magni aliquid eligendi quibusdam delectus iure nesciunt cupiditate, fugit ratione distinctio, rerum enim. Cumque recusandae dolores fugiat, totam deleniti eligendi et quas quasi necessitatibus
    placeat dolore doloremque ad cupiditate harum minima illum maxime veniam iste quam nesciunt fuga tempore. Dolores minus sequi iure neque velit adipisci ipsum rem quibusdam quia esse inventore nisi fugit voluptatibus repudiandae id, quos error laboriosam
    molestiae. Optio magnam distinctio at error tempore quos rem labore nobis cum in aspernatur corrupti ad, veritatis tempora provident ullam commodi excepturi ea accusamus dicta. Architecto aperiam necessitatibus ullam tempora omnis.</p>
</main>

<footer class="footer"></footer>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal__inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta, corrupti!

    <button id="button">click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не работает же - backdrop-filter - не кроссбраузерный

Comment: Увы, но, да. Даже FF - без поддрежки

Comment: к сожалению, да, вы оба правы, не кроссбраузерно, забыл добавить уточнение, но другого варианта я пока не придумал, ибо если на странице есть элементы с `position: fixed;`, то они просто ломаются (если на родителя вешать `filter: blur(*);`)

Comment: @meine почему ломаются? В моём примере, используя `:not()` можно обойти само окно и размывать всё, кроме него. Но, проблема с границами остаётся.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, в любое место добавьте элемент с фиксированным позиционированем, и понажимайте на кнопку блюра

Comment: @meine добавил второе окно сразу за модальным и ничего, размывается без проблем. Может в каком-то конкретном браузере что-то? Или я просто не вижу чего-то.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev [click](https://codepen.io/meine89/pen/abvbRbR)

Comment: Да, если внутри article. Есть такое дело. Интересный баг. Спасибо